# Week difference like today's date and and 7 days before date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want both ways whether I put the date in terms of -100 or a string date .So I use nvarchar because it accepts both integer as well as string values but it is not working please suggest me some solution.

The code is working fine in case of string date but in numeric it is creating problem

```
declare @date nvarchar(100);
declare @date1 nvarchar(100);
set @date = '2019-08-11'
set @date1= -100

select 
(case isdate(@date)
        when 1 then cast(@date as datetime)
        when 0 then dateadd(day,cast(@date as int),getdate())
                 end)
as fromDate,
(case isdate(@date1)
        when 1 then DATEADD(day, -7, convert(datetime,@date1,0))
        when 0 then dateadd(day,cast(-7 as 
int),convert(datetime,@date1,0))
                 end)
as toDate
```

I want the output of dates in such a manner it accepts both -100 or a string date
and return two dates like fromdate and todate but having 7 days gap.

Comment: Typically, to which date should value `-100` be converted?

Comment: such as today is 11 sep 2019 when i run i want

Comment: 11 sep as well as 4 sep

Comment: You're trying to convert @date1 to a datetime when you've confirmed it's not a date.

Comment: -100 was just a random number you can take any other

Comment: yes right you can say a field in which a user can enter date in both format but the second date will calculate automatically by entered date-7

Comment: actually i want to run a report which is on weekly basis so user will enter fromdate and the report will run till the last 7 days. todate does'nt need to enter by the user

Comment: However the most likely reason people aren't providing possible answers is that they cannot understand what you are asking - please add some sample data and expected results to your question - then you may find some people try and assist.

Comment: Ok i understand,if you just set date1 declaration you will the output that i only want but with the number also

Comment: Comment set date1 declaration you will the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a small error in your 2nd column case. You use @date1 instead of getdate() when the input is a number. 
Here is the fixed version

```
declare @date nvarchar(100);
declare @date1 nvarchar(100);
set @date = '2019-08-11'
set @date1= -100

select 
(case isdate(@date)
    when 1 then cast(@date as datetime)
    when 0 then dateadd(day,cast(@date as int),getdate())
             end) as fromDate,
(case isdate(@date1)
    when 1 then DATEADD(day, -7, 
convert(datetime,@date1,0))
    when 0 then dateadd(day,-7 + cast(@date1 as int),getdate())
             end) as toDate
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for your solution i caught my mistake later in night and i fixed that. Yes you are right this was my mistake.

Comment: @DevendraSingh, Just a kind reminder, once you get an answer that satisfy your question, you should mark/check the answer as the good one. Thanks

Comment: sorry i forgot ,now i added